# Android: Where to insert code in MainActivity

Tags: android, animation, android-activity

My MainActivity looks like this:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 


    ViewPager myViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    myViewPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    myViewPager.setCurrentItem(1, false);
}

private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
        switch(pos) {

        case 2: return FirstFragment.newInstance("FirstFragment, Instance 1");
        case 1: return SecondFragment.newInstance("SecondFragment, Instance 1");
        case 0: return ThirdFragment.newInstance("ThirdFragment, Instance 1");
        default: return ThirdFragment.newInstance("ThirdFragment, Default");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }       


    {}}}
```

and i want to insert this to add animation to some ImageButtons:

```
final ImageButton b = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.animation);
        b.startAnimation(anim);
    }
});

    final ImageButton c = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    c.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.animation);
        c.startAnimation(anim);
    }
});

    final ImageButton d = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
    d.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.animation);
        d.startAnimation(anim);
    }
});

}

}}
```

the animations work fine when separate but when i insert it to the MainActivity i get loads of errors, the problem is im not really sure where to insert this code without getting errors.

i have tried inserting at the end of onCreate(), then i get no errors but instead the application crashes when launched?
Here is the LogCat:

```
03-22 15:01:12.731: E/AndroidRuntime(28671): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-22 15:01:12.731: E/AndroidRuntime(28671): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start    activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-22 15:01:12.731: E/AndroidRuntime(28671):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2092)
03-22 15:01:12.731: E/AndroidRuntime(28671):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117)
03-22 15:01:12.731: E/AndroidRuntime(28671):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134)
03-22 15:01:12.731: E/AndroidRuntime(28671):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218)
03-22 15:01:12.731: E/AndroidRuntime(28671):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-22 15:01:12.731: E/AndroidRuntime(28671):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-22 15:01:12.731: E/AndroidRuntime(28671):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
03-22 15:01:12.731: E/AndroidRuntime(28671):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-22 15:01:12.731: E/AndroidRuntime(28671):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-22 15:01:12.731: E/AndroidRuntime(28671):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
03-22 15:01:12.731: E/AndroidRuntime(28671):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
03-22 15:01:12.731: E/AndroidRuntime(28671):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-22 15:01:12.731: E/AndroidRuntime(28671): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-22 15:01:12.731: E/AndroidRuntime(28671):    at com.example.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
03-22 15:01:12.731: E/AndroidRuntime(28671):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5047)
03-22 15:01:12.731: E/AndroidRuntime(28671):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
03-22 15:01:12.731: E/AndroidRuntime(28671):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2056)
03-22 15:01:12.731: E/AndroidRuntime(28671):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Have you tried to insert it into the end of onCreate() method?

Comment: The end of `onCreate()` would be the right place. Also make sure you have the resources (A layout with the button ids, an animation called animation)  in the resources folder.

Comment: I get no errors when i put it at the end of onCreate(), but now instead when i launch the application it crashes immediately :/

Comment: @da_st May be null pointer exception. add a line `if(b!=null)` before calling `b.setOnclickListener();`. If it's so, then your activity is unable to find buttons with specified ids. Means they are not in `activity_main.xml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this at the end of onCreate. Make sure the IDs are in the layout and your animation resource exists as well. This assumes the ImageButtons are in the activity's layout, not in a fragment.

```
final ImageButton b = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
final ImageButton c = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
final ImageButton d = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
final Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.animation);

final OnClickListener ocl = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        v.startAnimation(anim);
    }
};

b.setOnClickListener(ocl);
c.setOnClickListener(ocl);
d.setOnClickListener(ocl);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have my ImageButtons in a xml file called second_frag.xml, will this still work?

Comment: Then you have to put it in the onCreateView() of your SecondFrag class.

Comment: @da_st I highly recommend reading a book on Android programming.

Comment: @FD_ thanks for the tip ive been following the tutorials on androids website :) could you recommend any books ?

Comment: @da_st I personally don't like tutorials for learning, because you tend to just copy-paste instead of remembering and exploring it yourself. I cannot recommend a specific one though, the one I read was not in English.